# Why does NumberStyles.AllowThousands cause an exception when passing a negative number?

Tags: c#

I'm calling the following two lines. The second line crashes.:

```
var a = long.Parse("2,147,483,648", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
var b = long.Parse("-2,147,483,648", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

However, if I modify the values to not have ',' characters and remove the NumberStyles enum it works. e.g.

```
var a = long.Parse("2147483648");
var b = long.Parse("-2147483648");
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known issue? Is there an acceptable work-around that doesn't involve hacky string manipulation?

**edit** I should have mentioned the exception is a `System.FormatException`, "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your second example, you need to use `AllowLeadingSign` as well since you using [`NegativeSign`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign.aspx) in your string.

```
var b = long.Parse("-2,147,483,648",
                   NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign);
```

When you use [`long.Parse(string)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this method uses `NumberStyles.Integer` composite style which has *already* includes `AllowLeadingSign` itself.

From [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/numberstyles.cs,52);

```
Integer  = AllowLeadingWhite | AllowTrailingWhite | AllowLeadingSign,
```